# How to set placeholder for dropdown in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
<select>
     <option selected disabled>Select</option
```

I added an extra option with a disabled property, but this gives me the following warning:

> Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on select instead of setting
>   `selected` on option.

```
<select>
    {this.props.optionarray.map(function(e){
        return <option 
                   value={e[self.props.unique]} 
                   key={e[self.props.unique]}
               >
                   {e[self.props.name]}
               </option>
    })}
</select>
```

`optionarray` is an `array` which is passed through `props` to be mapped on each index which has an `object` and I pass the key through `props` as well which was in the array. Everything is working here, it's just showing me the warning that I mentioned above.

How do I remove that or how do I set a perfect placeholder for a dropdown in react?

Comment: Its not a question of `reactJs`. There is no concept of `placeholder` for a dropdown in `HTML`. You need add a option as `defaultValue` and handle it during your validation if it is selected or not. Or make use of `onChange` handlers to modify a state variable and check for its presence.

Comment: yes . defaultValue of select needs to have the unique value of selected option. instead i was not passing any value to it. giving a state to the value of select and updating the state did the magic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reason is, `React` provide a better way of controlling the element by using `states`, so instead of using `selected` with option use the value property of `select` and define its value in the `state` variable, use the `onChange` method to update the `state`, Use it in this way:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '1'
        };
    }

    render(){
       return(
           <select value={this.state.value} onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({value: e.target.value})}}>
              <option value='1' disabled>Select</option>
              {
                  [2,3,4].map((i,j)=>{
                      return <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
                  })
              }
           </select>
       );
    }
}
```

> How to set placeholder for dropdown?

According to [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), **placeholder** is not a valid attribute on a `<select>`. So in place of that you can you this also to render a `default` option:

`<option default>Select</option>`

**Use of key** as per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity.

**Suggestion:**

Whenever we create any `ui` `dynamically` in loop, we need to assign a `unique` key to each `element`, so that `react` can easily identify the element, it basically used to improve the `performance`.

Check the working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: '1'
    };
}

render(){
   return(
       <select value={this.state.value} onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({value: e.target.value})}}>
          <option value='1' disabled>Select</option>
          {
              [2,3,4].map((i,j)=>{
                  return <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
              })
          }
       </select>
   );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Check the fiddle for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/29uk8fn0/

Comment: yes you got it right, assign a unique value like '-1' or '0' to disabled option, and proper values to other option. disabled one will be the default one, so you can assign any value to it.

Comment: the key here is to give a unique value to disabled option. sorry i deleted my previous comment by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Functional Component**

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function DropdownComponent(props) {

  const [formData, setFromData] = useState({
    anyInput: "something",
    dropdownInput: null,
  });
  
  return (
          <>
            anyInput: { formData.anyInput }
            dropdownInput: { formData.dropdownInput }
            <select name={"dropdownName"} onChange={ ({target})=> {
                    setFromData((prev)=> ({...prev, dropdownInput:target?.value}) );
                }
            }>
                <option key='blankKey' hidden value >Placeholder Text for Select</option>
                {
                    [2,3,4].map((i,j)=>{
                        return <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
                    })
                }
            </select>
          </>
         )
}
```