# Select element placeholder in react

Tags: html, reactjs, select, placeholder

i'm trying to add placeholer to select element in react. At this moment im using:

```
<option disabled selected hidden>{props.placeholder || "Select options"}</option>
```

But i'm getting warning:

```
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
```

I have already tried defaultValue and few others, but nothing works.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set placeholder for dropdown in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315990/how-to-set-placeholder-for-dropdown-in-react-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React, you don't add the `selected` attribute to the option-tag, but you need to specify a [`defaultValue`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) prop ([Uncontrolled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)) or define the value prop ([Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)) in your select-tag.

Here is an example of uncontrolled:

```
<select defaultValue="apple">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't specify `defaultValue` at all, or empty string on value in controlled components.